# pdf.worker.js PDF not loading in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

When i try to open the PDF in viewer getting the below error

[Attached the screen shot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hvoV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Why use pdf.worker.js ?

If you want just read the PDF use `<embed src="/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">` or `<object>`

You can find more example here https://pdfobject.com/static.html

Comment: that's not exactly what I need, but thnks anyway

Comment: I need answer for the question above